# angular-loading-bar event how to make that function worked by Event?

Tags: angularjs

there is link https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar .This plugin has event.how to make that function worked by Event?

Comment: Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

1. pass the cfpLoadingBar in the controller like

   ```
   controller('ExampleCtrl', function (cfpLoadingBar) {});
   ```
2. After that you can use this service like

   ```
   $scope.start = function() {
     cfpLoadingBar.start();
   };

   $scope.complete = function () {
     cfpLoadingBar.complete();
   }
   ```

For more information follow the [example](https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar/blob/master/example/app.js) section on github

Comment: how do I know when the page is loaded already?by Event call function

Comment: @user6355594 didn't get your question